# Why is the alpha particle beam in the Rutherford experiment not affected by the electrons?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, atomic-physics, scattering, coulombs-law

The force exerted by the nucleus on the alpha particles is electrostatic in nature. So, why does mass has an effect? How do we conclude that the electrons don't effect the alpha particles from the fact that the mass of the electrons is negligible although they have the same charge as of the protons in the nucleus.

Comment: Friendly reminder: use comments to improve questions. Comments which answer the question may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply related to theory of elastic collisions. Even if you take the case of head-on collisions, in which maximum transfer of momentum takes place, the velocity of projectile and target after collision in lab frame is:

$$v_{projectile}= -\left(\frac{m_2-m_1}{m_1+m_2}\right)v$$

And
$$v_{target}= \left(\frac{2m_1}{m_1+m_2}\right)v$$

where $v$ is incident velocity in lab frame, $m_1$ is mass of projectile and $m_2$ is mass of target.

You can easily see that in the case $m_1>>m_2$, $v_{projectile}$ is approximately same as initial velocity, while the target velocity is approximately twice the incident velocity.

So, change in momentum of heavier particle is negligible if the other particle is very light.
This is the same case as with electrons and alpha particles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as far as I know the above two equations are only applicable in a situation when there is no interaction between the particles before and after the collision i.e, when they only exert force on each other when they are in contact ,which is clearly not the case .The electrons exert forces of equal magnitude as the protons on the alpha particles .

Comment: You can consider them for before and after interaction. Like the particles started at infinite distances apart, interacted when they were finite distance apart, and final stage is again infinite distance apart.

Comment: wait! if $m_{1}>>m_{2}$ then the electrons should be affected.Why aren't they affected?

Comment: The electrons do get affected by the alpha beam. See this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/110774/162251

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment.

The alpha particles are helium nuclei , no electrons, and have charge +2. They are very much heavier than the electrons, so in classical electrodynamic scattering with electrons , the interaction will be very small.

The contemporary theory of how a metal foil , like the gold in the experiment, was composed was the [plumb pudding model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93Marsden_experiments#Summary). That the atom was composed of a uniformly distributed posite charge with the electrons embedded so that the whole atom was neutral. There was no concept of positive charge particles existing in the atom.

That is what was tested, whether the gold atoms, electrons and positive charges, had that distribution.

[image: plumbpud]

The experiment showed that there was a hard core in the atom, and not the uniformly distributed charges as in the plumb pudding model.